# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install and error related to running abd

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am a newcomer in android studio and flutter. I am aware of that this question asked and answered, but, unfortunately it steadies for me.
When I run my flutter project the following error occurs in the run box of android studio.

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\project\Flutter\flutter_app9\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]
Error launching application on G011A.
```

I search more time and obey all of the current steps in the bellow.

```
1)flutter clean
2)adb kill and then start in terminal or CMD
3)download platform-tools and replaced it by the old one.
4)set variable related to abd in Path
5)download Gradle on reallocated it and android studio 
6)change my emulator from  to memu
7)Disable Antivirus and firewall
8)upgrade my flutter by newer version of powershell
```

All in all, I am so exhausted by this problem, additionally, in the event box of android studio there some cues which tell me a tricky issue around abd exist which will mention in the below.

```
12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:32 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:34 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:34 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:34 PM    adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (41); killing...

12:34 PM    * daemon started successfully

12:34 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:34 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused: connect, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused: connect

12:35 PM    Failed to start monitoring 127.0.0.1:21503

12:35 PM    adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (41); killing...

12:35 PM    * daemon started successfully

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Failed to start monitoring 127.0.0.1:21503

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

12:35 PM    Failed to start monitoring 127.0.0.1:21503

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Failed to start monitoring 127.0.0.1:21503

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:35 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:35 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:36 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:36 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:36 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:36 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:36 PM    adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (41); killing...

12:36 PM    * daemon started successfully

12:36 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:36 PM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

12:36 PM    adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (41); killing...

12:36 PM    * daemon started successfully
```

I apologize for along and bored question.

Comment: wipe your emulator data and run again

Comment: My emulator is Memu and I clean it. There isn't any place in AVD manager of android for installing emulator which are independent or not embedded. I mentioned that reinstall a new one.

Answer (score 1):

After suffering from my mentioned problem, I can find out the solution of my question. Indeed, two reasons cause my project to fail, which I would like to describe both of them with their answers.

**The first problem:**

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\project\Flutter\flutter_app9\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]
Error launching application on G011A.
```

Answer for the first problem:

It brings from privilege policy in android, because, there is a security spot in google play which restrict unauthorized installation. Obviously, I sign in google play and turn off protection in setting,led to this challenge is solved. Finally, syncing between android studio and emulator correctly done.
**The Second problem:**

```
12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!

12:31 PM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

12:31 PM    Sending Tracking request failed!
```

You have to navigate all the adb files in your pc, and they should have the same version. For example, the prominent one is adb in your emulator, which huge amount of problems go back to that. Therefore, by replacing all of them with newer version in platform-tools folder of SDK, fortunately, I rescue the first one.