"Android emulator exited with code -1073741819" when i run flutter program
so when i run the program the the emulater crashes and output these errors
[ERR] Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 x86 64:
[ERR] adb.exe: device 'emulator-5554' not found

[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -1073741819 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): SupportPixelFold
[ERR] WARN: Renderer11.cpp:889 (initializeD3DDevice): Failed creating Debug D3D11 device - falling back to release runtime.
[ERR] WARN: Renderer11.cpp:889 (initializeD3DDevice): Failed creating Debug D3D11 device - falling back to release runtime.
[ERR] WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.

i tried updating the emulater and i tried deleting the app then running it and it did't work

Maybe the below link would be useful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436862/error-adb-exited-with-exit-code-1-performing-streamed-install-and-error-related?noredirect=1#comment117451643_66436862
